# How to match ONLY the first string between the first semi-colon and the preceding space using a regular expression

Tags: java, regex

Here are more details:
I have a list delivered by an external provider. It contains a field that can have different content for the records it contains: sometimes records have commas, sometimes they have commas and semi-colons, and multiple occurrences of these characters. To be more clear, here are some examples:

Record 1
city, country

Record 2
city, region, country

Record 3
city1, region1, country1; city2, region2, country2; city3, region3, country3

Although at first I was only able to find a regex that allows me to filter the country from record 1, I am now able to select the countries in all 3 of the records (see below for tests executed in regex101). The part that I am struggling with is:

- to get **only ** the *first* country in record 3, i.e. the string between the first semi-colon and the preceding space. I am not interested in the remaining string after the first semi-colon.

**Testing history**
I have tried several regular expressions, the best of which are below:

```
(?<=, ).+|(?<=,).+?(?=;)
```

This will select:

- only the country in record 1 = PASS
- both the region and the country in record 2 = FAIL
- both the region and the country preceding all semi-colons (region1, country1, region2, country2 etc.) = FAIL

I have also tried the following:

```
[^,]*[;\n]|;.*
```

This will select:

- only the country in record 1 = PASS
- only the country in record 2 = PASS
- all countries in the string before each semi-colon = FAIL

The last regex does select the right part of the string (just before the semi-colon up to the preceding space), but it needs to stop after the first match of such a string.
If I could trim the leading space and get rid of the semi-colon and the carriage return that would be a bonus.

Comment: I personally would prefer calling split(";") then processing the first item in the array using your third regex that works for the first 2 records

Answer (score 1):

I would first use a string split on semicolon to reduce the first city/country entry (if a given record have more than one entry in the first place).

```java
String input = "New York, Northeast, United States; Berlin, Europe, Germany; Singapore, Southeast Asia, Singapore";
String first = input.split(";")[0];
String pattern = "\\w+(?: \\w+)*$";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(first);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());  // United States
}
```

Answer (score 0):

regex: `([^,]+)$|([^,]*;).*?$`

demo: https://regex101.com/r/yybdAM/1

Answer (score 0):

I think you could firstly split based on `;` to get the seperate entries. Then for each entry you could use the following regex

```
^([^,]+)(?:,([^,]+))?,([^,]+)$
```

- `^` start of string
- `([^,]+)` capturing group for the city (the not of comma one or more times)
- `(?:,([^,]+))?` optional region group (outer group non capturing, inner group is capturing)
- `,([^,]+)` - country
- `$` end of string

You can play around with this regex (see the capturing groups etc) at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lMA4Ua/1)

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me: (?:[^,]+, ?){1,2}([^;]+)

Here's my Java code:

```
        var input = new String[] {
                "city, country",
                "city, region, country",
                "city1, region1, country1; city2, region2, country2; city3, region3, country3" };
        
        var p = Pattern.compile("(?:[^,]+, ?){1,2}([^;]+)");
        for(String s : input)
        {
            var m = p.matcher(s);
            if(m.find())
            {
                System.out.println(m.group(1));
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if your regex matches more than one substring in a string, every call to `Matcher.find()` returns only one find. You can then call `Matcher.group()` to get only the group you're interested in.

For example, the following regex will always match the country as group 3:

```
;?(.*?, )?(.*?),\s(.*?)(;|$)
```

You can test this regular expression here: https://regex101.com/r/D3ZEpV/1

Then you can do something like:

```
    String str = "city1, region1, country1; city2, region2, country2; city3, region3, country3" ;
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(";?(.*?, )?(.*?),\\s(.*?)(;|$)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    m.find();
    System.out.println(m.group(3)); // prints "country1"
```